# Apache Falcon fails to submit Cluster definition

Tags: apache, hadoop

I am attempting to submit a cluster definition to a running Apache falcon server. The server is running in distributed node with a Prism instance in front of it. 
Both are running over http and local to my machine. I am executing the following command

```
falcon entity -type cluster -submit -file /projects/falcon/examples/primary-cluster.xml
```

With the result being:

```
 
Client Response POST http://localhost:16000/api/entities/submit/cluster returned a response status of 400 Bad Request
Error: Bad Request;local/Current colo (default) is not local
```

So I guess my question here would be what does *local/Current colo (default) is not local* means I think it's an xml error but I can't be 100%. I've run a unit test parsing the file I am submitting against the appropriate xsd and it parsed it just fine.

Here is the xml I am sending (primary-cluster.xml)

```
<cluster colo="default" description="Primary Cluster"
     name="local-cluster"
     xmlns="uri:falcon:cluster:0.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<tags>class=dev,site=local</tags>
<interfaces>    
    <interface type="readonly" endpoint="hftp://localhost:50010" version="1.1.2"/>
    <interface type="write" endpoint="hdfs://localhost:9000" version="2.4.0"/>
    <interface type="execute" endpoint="localhost:9001" version="2.4.0"/>
    <interface type="workflow" endpoint="http://localhost:11000/oozie/" version="4.0.1"/>
    <interface type="messaging" endpoint="tcp://localhost:61616?daemon=true" version="5.4.3"/>
</interfaces>
<locations>
    <location name="staging" path="/staging"/>
    <location name="temp" path="/tmp"/>
    <location name="working" path="/working"/>
</locations>
```

*The xml xsd can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-falcon/blob/master/client/src/main/resources/cluster-0.1.xsd)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be fairly easy. I had my prism instance mis-configured. The error i was seeing is not one of xml parsing rather saying that a certain colo doesn't have a cluster i am trying to upload to.

So go to your $PRISM_HOME/config/runtime.properties (or whenever you've put your runtime properties) and add the following line

```
 prism.falcon.default.endpoint=http://localhost:15000
```

where ***default*** is actually the name I gave to the loco ( rather the default name, haven't figured out yet how to change it). Localhost is where i have deployed my falcon instance and 15000 is the port it's running.

Hope that helps,
Cheers Peter